# Creating a folder and multiple sub-folders with a batch file

Tags: batch-file, mkdir

I'm currently looking to create a folder with multiple sub-folders with a batch file. The folders will be located on an external drive when its created.

I've done:

`mkdir test\{subTest,subTest2,subTest3}`

Which creates a test folder but it also creates separate folders for `subTest`,`subTest2`, and `subTest3}` which are not sub-folders to `test`

I've also tried:

`md a:\test\subTest`

Which works as it should, but I will need more folders added into the test folder.

`a:\` is the drive letter for where they should be created

Would someone be able to provide a solution for this?

Comment: `md a:\test\subTest` `md a:\test\subTest2` `md a:\test\subTest3`

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Thank you very much! I thought of that I just wasn't sure if there was any way reduce the amount of lines that would be needed to create the all of folders. There might be 10-15 folders that need to be created.

Comment: `for %%D in ("subTest" "subTest2" "subTest3") do mkdir "a:\test\%%~D"`

Comment: @aschipfl Perfect! Thats exactly what I was looking to do. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@aschipfl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5047996/aschipfl) had answered the question in the comments above.

`for %%D in ("subTest" "subTest2" "subTest3") do mkdir "a:\test\%%~D"`

Comment: I always suggest the `-p` option on `mkdir` when auto generating folders. It really sucks to have a script hang because and intermediary folder got incorrectly deleted.